# Scanning Network Mac SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, ios4, xcode4

I have a question. I have a c# application that scans the network and finds all active IP address on the network. I want to do this in Objective C for a Mac application, does anyone know on how to build a simple network scanner or know of any sample code I could take a look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Apple's [Reachability sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) may help you, or see the [Connection and Reachability APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_ReachConnect/SC_ReachConnect.html).

Comment: You use the reachability API to determine if data destined for a remote host can leave the local machine. Not to test if a host is online or not.